# How to create database project from existing SQL Server database?

Tags: sql, database, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2005

By using VS TFS Database Edition 2008, how to create dbproject from an existing SQL SERVER database?

Comment: can u please tell me how to increase that...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There no direct, built-in support to do that, unfortunately.

You can get close by doing this:

- in SQL Server Management Studio, go to the Object Explorer, right-click on the database you want, and pick Tasks > Generate Scripts
- select all the database objects you want to script out
- at the end, choose to generate the scripts into separate files for each db object

What you end up with are a number of .sql scripts in a folder of your choice, which basically represent your database.

Next:

- create a Database Project in Visual Studio 2008
- once you've done that, add the existing scripts to that project

It's a bit more involved that it should be - but that's the only way that I know of to achieve this right now. Don't know if VS2010 will support this in an easier way....

Answer (score 6):

This as updated in VS 2010.  There is now the option to "Import database objects and settings" from the project context menu.

Answer (score 6):

In "Visual Studio" go to the "SQL Server Object Explorer" locate to database, right-click on the database you want and select "Create New Project ..."